# Crear diccionario a partir de un json JMESPath

Tags: python, json

El json contiene diversos índices, dentro de ellos se encuentra "phoneNumbers" y su valor es un diccionario; por lo que al querer normalizarlo, no puedo obtener el valor correspondiente a "Home" o "Mobile"

> 

```
 [{
  "name": "John Doe",
  "age": 35,
  "address": {
    "street": "123 Main St",
    "city": "Anytown",
    "state": "WA"
  },
  "phoneNumbers": [
    {
      "type": "mobile",
      "number": "555-551-1234"
    },
    {
      "type": "home",
      "number": "555-552-5678"
    }
  ],
  "email": "john.doe@example.com"
}
```

Y requiero modificarlo para que la salida sea esta:

```
[{"mobile": "555-555-1234",
"home": "555-556-5678"}]
```